# JADX gets class names from obfuscated app

Tags: android, proguard

My app is set up with proguard:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /Users/nerdywoffy/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
```

Also gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 17
        versionName "1.1.6"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
    }

    buildTypes {
        studioDebug {
            debuggable true
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

But when decompiling the APK with JADX, it gets all class names somehow. Why might this be happening? AFAIK my release builds aren't debuggable, so it can't be because of that.

Comment: have you found the proper solution ?

Comment: @paulsenjs No, I have not. Surprisingly, when generating app bundle and publishing to google play, this doesn't happen

Comment: hmm.. were there any clues about this ? i'm checking in Android Developer documentation site but didn't find any.